# AIR AS3 for Mobile - Download zip file crash the application

Tags: actionscript-3, file, air, crash, local-storage

I've make an application with AIR and ActionScript 3 *( Using the IntelliJ IDE )*

At start of the application, it loads some zip file and extracts their files to put them in the local storage. For futur use *( Or an utilisation if the user kills then re-opens the application )*

It works correctly without problem the most of the time except that I have, sometimes, with a very low rate of appearence, a crash of the application during the download of those zip files.
The strange thing is these crash can occur directly in the emulator on my computer *( With a message that indicates an error in AIR ).*

It is really difficult to check because these crashes may occur, something, like one time on forty launches and seems to never occur when **trace()** are with the debug mode.
That makes me think it's probably a problem with the speed of the loading, because all **trace()** slows down the launches and files loading.
Apparently, it's not a memory crash. I've tested and used the same code to load a really high number of same zip together and it doesn't crash.

I can't directly show the code, because it is implanted in a more complex framework.
The concerned code is something near to this :

```
private static function fileLoad( url:String ):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader( "pragma" , "no-cache" );

    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, complete );

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( url );
    request.requestHeaders.push( header );
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    loader.load( request );
}

private static function complete( event:Event ):void
{
    var file:File;

    file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( "ZIP.zip" );
    var bytes:ByteArray  = event.target.data as ByteArray;
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();

    stream.open( file , FileMode.WRITE );
    stream.writeBytes( bytes );
    stream.close();

    var loadZip:Function = function( event:FZipEvent ):void
    {
        var zip:FZipFile = event.file;

        if ( zip.sizeUncompressed != 0 )
        {
            var fileData:Object = {};
            var file:File = outputFile.resolvePath( zip.filename );
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();

            file.preventBackup = true;
            stream.open( file, FileMode.WRITE );
            stream.writeBytes( zip.content );
            stream.close();
        }
    };

    var inputFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( "ZIP.zip" );
    var outputFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( "folderZip" );

    var zipFileBytes:ByteArray = event.target.data as ByteArray;
    stream = new FileStream();

    stream.open( inputFile , FileMode.READ );
    stream.readBytes( zipFileBytes );
    stream.close();

    var zip:FZip = new FZip();
    zip.addEventListener( FZipEvent.FILE_LOADED , loadZip );
    zip.load( new URLRequest( inputFile.nativePath ) );
}
```

I don't really expect a total solution but, if you have encountered a similar problem, I'll be thankfull to know what you've done to resolve it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: how many zip files are we talking about?

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of response, I've keep searching in my program and it appear that this bug doesn't comes from the zip file but was in another section. Thanks.